# What are the physical dimensions of the other Dominion cards (e.g. Landscape, Boon etc.)?

Tags: dominion

There is a fair number of answers all over the web about the dimensions of the regular playing cards in Dominion (91x59 mm). However there are a large number of other cards in the expansions etc. I'm trying to design a box to hold everything but I do not own all the expansions (yet).

**Does anybody have the dimensions (HxWxT) of all the *other* cards and a count of how many of each card there are currently?**

I'm talking about things like (but not limited to) the Landscape, Boon cards etc. but also would appreciate dimensions of other things that you would deem necessary to store in a single box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Landscape-style cards in Dominion have the same exact size as regular Dominion cards; they're printed on the same card base. They are designed to be shuffled in along with the randomizer deck for the regular cards in order to randomize which cards + non-cards are used in each game.

There are several types of these landscape cards. Here is a list, along with the number that exist for each:

- Ally (23)
- Artifact (5)
- Boon (12)
- Event (69)
- Hex (12)
- Landmark (21)
- Project (20)
- State (13)
- Trait (15)
- Way (20)

Grand total of 210 of these cards as of the the Plunder expansion.

Aside from these, there are also several playing mats in the game, which a storage solution would ideally also have room for:

- Island, Pirate Ship, and Native Village mats (6 each): 82×126mm
- Trade Route mat (1): 80×80mm
- Victory token player mat (8): 80×80mm
- Tavern player mat (6): 125×82mm
- Trash mat (1): 190×102mm
- Coffers player mat (6): 126×84mm
- Coffers / Villagers player mat (6): 84×128mm
- Exile player mat (6): 128x84mm
- Favors player mat (6): 127x84mm

All information from http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Card_types and http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Mat#Player_mats.

Comment: This is awesome - thanks!!